# flutter on error opens a internal file rather than showing error in debug console

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, error-handling, runtime-error

when my app runs an error occurs, but instead of showing error in debug console it opens a file and highlights a line from the `error_patch.dart` file. This have happen multiple times with some other file or error. Does flutter not show error in debug console like it should! or am I missing something!

[image: error location]

Answer (score 1):

I often meet this problem. You could do this 3 cases:

- Run in terminal tab "flutter run" instead of press F5, now VSCode gives you error and not take to through all unnecessary files.
- Try to press first play button ||> until it stops :)
- Press Ctrl + F5 (Run without debugging),

Comment: thank you for your answer I will try the mentioned techniques